# Nodejs/MongoDB : $in needs an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

what I am trying to do , is to join two collections and then return elements whome names exist inside an array

these are the models

CarModel

```
id,
carAuthorizedDrivers:[String],
garageId:{type: Schema.ObjectId,ref:"garage"}
```

driversModel

```
id,
garageId:{type: Schema.ObjectId,ref:"garage"}
drivers:[{name:String,skill:String}]
```

this is the result of the join

```
{
"id":"1D99399379773",
"carAuthorizedDrivers":["DriverA","DriverB"],
"garageId":"010003",
"JoinDrivers":[drivers:[{"name":"DriverA","skill":"89"},{"name":"DriverB","skill":"77"},{"name":"DriverC","skill":"45"}]]
}
```

I want to restrict Joindrivers for the purpose of only showing drivers(name+skills) whome names belong to carAuthorizedDrivers , so I want joinDrivers to contain only the following :

```
{"name":"DriverA","skill":"89"},{"name":"DriverB","skill":"77"}
```

what i tried to do is the following :

```
join () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      Car.aggregate([
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'drivers', // collection name in db
            localField: 'garage_id',
            foreignField: 'garage_id',
            as: 'joinDrivers'
          }
        },
        { $unwind: '$Joindrivers' },
        { $unwind: '$Joindrivers.drivers' },
        { $unwind: '$carAuthorizedDrivers' },
        { $match: { 'Joindrivers.drivers.name': { $in: 'carAuthorizedDrivers' } } }
      ]).exec((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err)
        }
        resolve(result)
      })
    })
  }
```

I get  **$in needs an array ERROR** , but if I put an Array manually like this :

```
$match: { 'Joindrivers.drivers.name': { $in: ["DriverA","DriverB"] } }
```

$in works well and I get the result , how do I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compare or match two document fields within an aggregation's `$match` stage, you have to use an aggregation operator [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html) (*not* the query language operator [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html)). And, to use the aggregation operator in the `$match` stage, you must use the [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) operator.

So, your match stage should be:

```
{ $match: { $expr: { $in: [ "$Joindrivers.drivers.name", "$carAuthorizedDrivers" ] } } }
```

---

The following code uses the output from the lookup stage to filter based on the provided condition:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
{ $unwind: "$JoinDrivers" },
{ $addFields: { 
       "JoinDrivers.drivers": {
            $filter: {
                input: "$JoinDrivers.drivers", as: "driver",
                cond: {
                    $in: [ "$$driver.name", "$carAuthorizedDrivers" ] 
                }
            }
       }
}},
] )
```

Comment: This didn't work , it returned : $in requires an array as a second argument, found: string

Comment: Is this field `carAuthorizedDrivers` an array?

Comment: You can comment the `{ $unwind: '$carAuthorizedDrivers' },` and try; it will work.

Comment: If you want to keep the `{ $unwind: '$carAuthorizedDrivers' }` stage, then use this: `{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$Joindrivers.drivers.name", "$carAuthorizedDrivers" ] } } }`. Please note the [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html#examples) makes the string array into strings.

Comment: it repeats the same object twice , let's say a Car has << carAuthorizedDrivers":["DriverA","DriverB"]>> it sends back a Car with "DriverA" inside Joindrivers followed but the same Car with "DriverB" inside Joindrivers

Comment: That is how the `$unwind` works. See the link I had posted in my previous comment.

Comment: I removed the  ```{ $unwind: '$carAuthorizedDrivers' } ```as you said and I got the same Car twice , if I remove ```{ $unwind: '$Joindrivers' },
        { $unwind: '$Joindrivers.drivers' }``` I get an empty array back , is there a solution to group both drivers in JoinDrivers

Comment: You can use `$filter` aggregation operator, instead of the multiple unwind and the match stages - apply this filter immediately after the lookup stage..

Comment: I tried that before $match it didn't work that why I tried $match

Comment: The document after the join _this is the result of the join_: can you check once again, it is not correct. It has to be a proper JSON. Can you please update that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209980/discussion-between-prasad-and-mascor).

Answer (score 0):

You mixed the Query operator [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html) with the Aggregation operator [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html)

Try this one:

```
{ $match: { $in: ["$Joindrivers.drivers.name", ["DriverA", "DriverB"] } }
```

Comment: <<Error : unknown top level operator: $in>>
and I want to use carAuthorizedDrivers instead of ['DriverA','DriverB']